# leaflet: How to find locations around marker?

Tags: javascript, php, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I using leaflet map + leaflet search plugin (https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/nominatim.html).

So, when i navigate with marker on map i want to search all places around the marker. For example the marker is located in Roma (Italy) then i want to retrieve all restaurants, night clubs .... from Roma.

Its possible to do that ??

```
    // click on marker
    map.on('click', function(e){  

            // update marker position
            marker.setLatLng( e.latlng);

            ....HERE CODE TO SEARCH PLACES....
 });
```

Comment: Where are your getting all the locations from?Your own database?

Comment: @sbkashis, No, i using http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ API

Comment: Nominatim API lets you search for certain things within a bounding box (a set of four coordinates), you will need to either calculate those or use the user's browser bbox provided by Leaflet's `map.getBounds()` ([see docs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)). Not sure how capable the plugin is you are using. If you want to try out Overpass-API take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/chk1/b5wgds4n/) maybe. It fetches just trees, so keep in mind that there might be *a lot* of results.

Comment: thanks @chrki, helped the way with trees.

Answer (score 2):

@Bogza You'll need to complement this plugin with anothers libraries to achive it. Nominatim is to search locations by name. Once you get the location (lat, lng) the rest of the work is up to you. You need to have a geojson or similar with the restaurants'geographical locations. Then you could try to find the nearests ones with either of these libraries:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil) using  L.GeometryUtil.closestLayer.
https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn

PS: I had to answer because I couln't post a comment.